# Rails Guides - Stuck on Multi Model Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going working through the Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html),and am stuck at item 11 "Building a Multi Model Form".

This part of the excercise explains about including form fields for one model inside a form for another...

My problem is that the form fields for the second model just aren't displaying..

The code is exactly as per the excercise (I even got desperate and copy and pasted the code straight from the sample)

My code is posted below.. I have spent hours comparing this to the code in the guide, and it is exactly the same.. can anyone point me to what might be going wrong?

Many Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for including the partial

```
<%= render :partial => 'tags/form',
             :locals => {:form => post_form} %>
```

Here is the contents of my partial

```
<p>Above - THIS IS DISPLAYING</p>

<%= form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>

  <p>Inside - THIS IS NOT DISPLAYING</p>

  <div class="field">
    <%= tag_form.label :name, 'Tag:' %>
    <%= tag_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <% unless tag_form.object.nil? || tag_form.object.new_record? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= tag_form.label :_destroy, 'Remove:' %>
      <%= tag_form.check_box :_destroy %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my model for Post, which is set to accept nested attributes for tags

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5 }

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => :true,
    :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you do this?

> We also add a **@post.tags.build** at the top of this form. This is to
>   make sure there is a new tag ready to have its name filled in by the
>   user. If you do not build the new tag, then the form will not appear
>   as there is no new Tag object ready to create.

```
<% @post.tags.build %>
<%= form_for(@post) do |post_form| %>
…
```

If that doesn't work, try adding `@post.tags.build` into the `new` method of your PostController and see if that brings you the fields!

Comment: That was it.. I've spent hours looking through this code, and there it was.  Thank You!!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! I've spent hours in the past on this fields_for, too :)